# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\(path...)\site-packages\pyzbar\libzbar-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies

Tags: python, site-packages

I am getting **FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users(path...)\pythonProject\venv\lib\site-packages\pyzbar\libzbar-64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.** But, as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKrJE.png) here that libzbar-64.dll is stored in the above specified location.
**code is below , its supposed to be a qr code application using tkinter**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog

from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
import pyqrcode
import os

root = Tk()
root.title("QR code application")
note = ttk.Notebook(root)
note.pack()
# create frames to add on tabs
frame1 = Frame(note, height=400, width=150, bg='white')
frame1.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
frame2 = Frame(note, height=400, width=150, bg='white')
frame2.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_create("style", parent="alt", settings={
    "TNotebook.Tab": {"configure": {"padding": [20, 10],
                                    "font": ('Times', '20', 'bold')}}})
s.theme_use("style")
# add tabs
note.add(frame1, text="Generate QR Code")
note.add(frame2, text="Read QR Code")
# create canvas to display image
canvas1 = Canvas(frame1, width="400", height="300", relief=RIDGE, bd=2)
canvas1.pack(padx=10, pady=10)
canvas2 = Canvas(frame2, width="400", height="400", relief=RIDGE, bd=2)
canvas2.pack(padx=10, pady=10)


def generate():
    if data_entry.get() != '' and save_entry.get() != '':
        qr = pyqrcode.create(data_entry.get())
        img = qr.png(save_entry.get() + ".png", scale=5)
        info = Label(frame1, text="Generated QR code:", font=('ariel 15 bold'))
        info.place(x=60, y=40)
        img = Image.open(save_entry.get() + ".png")
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        canvas1.create_image(200, 180, image=img)
        canvas1.image = img
    else:
        info = Label(frame1, text="Please enter the data for QR code", font=('ariel 15 bold'))
        info.place(x=80, y=140)


def selected():
    img_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(),
                                          title="Select Image", filetype=(
            ("PNG file", "*.png"), ("All files", "*.*")))
    img = Image.open(img_path)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
    canvas2.create_image(200, 190, image=img)
    canvas2.image = img
    d = decode(Image.open(img_path))
    data = d[0].data.decode()
    qrcode_data = Label(frame2, text=data, bg='gold', fg='black', font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE)
    qrcode_data.place(x=150, y=380)


data_label = Label(frame1, text='Enter data:', font=('ariel 15 bold'), bg='white')
data_label.place(x=61, y=330)
save_label = Label(frame1, text='Enter name \n to save with:', font=('ariel 15 bold'), bg='white')
save_label.place(x=55, y=360)
data_entry = Entry(frame1, font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE, bd=3)
data_entry.place(x=197, y=330)
save_entry = Entry(frame1, font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE, bd=3)
save_entry.place(x=197, y=380)
btn1 = Button(frame1, text="Generate", bg='black', fg='gold', font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE, command=generate)
btn1.place(x=85, y=425)
btn2 = Button(frame1, text="Exit", width=10, bg='black', fg='gold', font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE,
              command=root.destroy)
btn2.place(x=255, y=425)
btn2 = Button(frame2, text="Select Image", bg='black', fg='gold', font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE,
              command=selected)
btn2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=50, pady=5)
btn3 = Button(frame2, text="Exit", width=12, bg='black', fg='gold', font=('ariel 15 bold'), relief=GROOVE,
              command=root.destroy)
btn3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=10, pady=5)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: how is this related to tkinter, qr-code or decoder?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error in my PyCharm environment.

Comment: wher did i go wrong then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same error. Reading on Pypi page, they say that in case of ImportError on Windows we should install "Visual C++ Redistributable Package per Visual Studio 2013"

I did and worked!

https://pypi.org/project/pyzbar/ , see "Windows Import Error".

Comment: i got the latest build of  visual c++ redistributable, does it change the thing or is about a specific version.......p.s. i still cant use  pyzbar

Comment: as i said, i installed that specific version, as explained on pypi, and worked.
I don't know if it would work with other versions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to import libzbar or pyzbar? if you're trying to import `pyzbar` it doesnt seem that `pyzbar` is in the site packages

Try to install pip install `pyzbar` first

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: pyzbar in c:\users\new user.laptop-5glt5pl6\pycharmprojects\pythonproject\venv\lib\site-packages (0.1.8)   its already there

Comment: Try and import `pyzbar` as `pyzbar` instead of `pyzbar.pzybar`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and tried to change python and PyCharm versions, but it still didn't work. Now I use python3.9.7 and PyCharm2020.2.5.

My error tip is "FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\python3.9.7\Lib\site-packages\PySmartCard\ReaderLib_64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax."

Strangely, I have this .dll file in my file path.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29857154)

Answer (score 0):

should install "Visual C++ Redistributable Package per Visual Studio 2013"

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=40784

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33357956)